# Autolayout how to grow as large as it can

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I'm using autolayout in my project but in this simple use case I cant seem to get it done. If got an label with a textfield next to it which has the vertical constraint:

H:|[searchLabel]-5-[searchText]|

Ofcourse a vertical constraint is there but this is beside the point of the question. What I want is the searchText to grow to the max left over space. Instead it is a very small box. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used compression resistance but now I've tried this and works perfectly:

```
[_searchLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Which according to a book i am reading means: "Content hugging describes a view's desire to match its frame to the natural size of its content"

Which does what I want :)